# how to add another same pagination with "bootstrap-table-rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, bootstrap-table

I'd like to add another same  pagination in a single table.
Now a pagination is showed in the bottom of the table but I want another one in the top of the table.
I have searched and I couldn't find any but I don't want to install another gem.
However, if there is no option with "bootstrap-table-rails" for sure, I would like to get recommendations.

Now, JS code is

```
$(document).bind("turbolinks:load", function(){
    var pageSize = Cookies.get("pageSize") || 50;
    $("#custom-table").bootstrapTable({pagination:true, pageNumber:Cookies.get("pageNumber"), pageSize:pageSize,  sortName:Cookies.get("sortName"), sortOrder:Cookies.get("sortOrder")});
```

and html is

```
table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-condensed data={toggle:"table", search:"true", pagination:"true", "page-size"=>50}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution with data.
I don't remember the site but I post the solution I've got.

in js file:

```
$("#custom-table").bootstrapTable({
    pagination:true,
    paginationVAlign:"both",   // added
    pageNumber: Cookies.get("pageNumber"),
    pageSize: pageSize,
    sortName: Cookies.get("sortName"),
    sortOrder: Cookies.get("sortOrder")
});
```

in slim file: added "pagination-v-align"=>"both"

```
table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-condensed data={ 
 toggle:"table", search:"true", pagination:"true", 
 "pagination-v-align"=>"both", "page-size"=>50}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps may be that will help you

**CREATE DIV:**

```
<div id="top-pagination"></div>
```

**MODIFY JS**

```
$(document).bind("turbolinks:load", function(){
    var pageSize = Cookies.get("pageSize") || 50;

    // Initialize the bottom pagination
    $("#custom-table").bootstrapTable({
        pagination: true,
        pageNumber: Cookies.get("pageNumber"),
        pageSize: pageSize,
        sortName: Cookies.get("sortName"),
        sortOrder: Cookies.get("sortOrder")
    });

    // Initialize the top pagination
    $("#top-pagination").bootstrapTable({
        pagination: true,
        pageNumber: Cookies.get("pageNumber"),
        pageSize: pageSize,
        sortName: Cookies.get("sortName"),
        sortOrder: Cookies.get("sortOrder")
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn' t work.